# Server holding user information

Tags: java

I'm trying to write myself a game server for educational purposes. 
I need to have some sort of list containing all the online users, their names and their X and Y positions.

What'd be the smartest way to hold this? I was thinking some sort of a multidimensional array or arraylist? Code examples as well would be great, i'm very new at Java :-)

Comment: The correct answer to this depends how you want to use this data.  Does it have to persist after the application stops running (in which case use a database)?  Do you have to be able to do lookups by user id (that is, given the user id, determine the position)?  Do you have to determine which users are close to a given location?  Until you specify the answers to questions like these, there is no correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an `ArrayList` of a Class you could maybe call `User`.

You could hold all the information like username, x and y position in said class.

I realize this is a very general answer, but it's a very general question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have a database to hold your user information permanently. And when the user is online his information is to be held in a bean. You should read about Java Bean Scopes in JSF, for example.